# Using one world file for multiple rasters

Tags: qgis, world-file

I have 400 PNG files all of the same area that are not gereferenced. I have gereferenced one of them and want to use the world file for all the others. I could copy it and rename the files but that will take forever. It there a way in QGIS to point the png files to a worldfile?

Comment: I don't think there is a way that doesn't involve writing a little program to do it, which you could do in python and run in the QGIS console. If you are on a Mac or Linux machine (or Windows with the Linux command stuff) you could also write a shell script program to do it, which is what I'd probably do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it using shell script.

Here's a folder with a bunch of `.png` files, and a folder called `world` which has a single world file in it.

```
.
├── arg.png
├── f1.png
├── f2.png
├── f3.png
├── world
│   └── f2.pngw
└── zz.png
```

I've set things up like this, temporarily separating `f2.png` from its world file just to make things a bit cleaner for the next step. Which is to run the following command from my terminal:

```
for f in *.png ; do cp world/f2.pngw ${f}w ; done
```

and now my folder looks like this:

```
.
├── arg.png
├── arg.pngw
├── f1.png
├── f1.pngw
├── f2.png
├── f2.pngw
├── f3.png
├── f3.pngw
├── world
│   └── f2.pngw
├── zz.png
└── zz.pngw
```

Every `png` has a `pngw` copied from the one in `world/f2.pngw`.

This `for` line works by looping over all files that match `*.png` and executing `cp world/f2.pngw ${f}w`, where `${f}` is the `png` file name being worked on. Hence it does:

```
cp ./world/f1.pngw ./f1.pngw
cp ./world/f1.pngw ./zz.pngw
cp ./world/f1.pngw ./arg.pngw
cp ./world/f1.pngw ./f2.pngw
```

and so on for all the `png` files, even if there's 400, in one go.

This should work from Mac and Linux terminals, and it is possible to install something that will do exactly this in Windows, although I forget what its called these days (Windows Linux Subsystem or something???)

Comment: Thanks Spacedman. I need to wrap my head around this and figure out the windows version.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in windows cmd batch file? My system does not want to install any linux subsystems?

Comment: I have next to no skills with Windows CMD stuff, and if I was forced to do this on a Windows box I'd use Python in QGIS. Python has a full set of file copy and rename utilities.